# How to optimize CasperJS project using Google Closure?

Tags: google-closure-compiler, casperjs

I'm trying to optimize the CasperJS tests run.js code(https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/blob/master/tests/run.js), so that I could understand how I can use it further to optimize further the tests that I've written. Here's the sample run.js of the CasperJS project that I was trying to optimize using ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS flag to the compiler.
(https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/blob/master/tests/run.js)
But the optimized code is as below:

```
phantom.d || (console.log("This script must be invoked using the casperjs executable"), phantom.c(1)); var a = require("fs"), c = require("utils").h, d = require("casper").create({g:!1}); d.options.n = d.a.get("direct") || !1; d.options.i = d.a.get("log-level") || "error"; d.m("open.location", function(b) { return!/^http/.test(b) ? c("file://%s/%s", phantom.e, b) : b }); var e = []; d.a.b.length ? e = d.a.b.filter(function(b) { return a.isFile(b) || a.isDirectory(b) }) : (d.f("No test path passed, exiting.", "RED_BAR", 80), d.c(1)); d.test.j("tests.complete", function() { this.k(true, void 0, d.a.get("xunit") || void 0) }); d.test.l.apply(d.test, e);
```

Obviously, this is failing as being told by the compiler (Ex: JSC_INEXISTENT_PROPERTY: Property casperLoaded never defined on phantom at line 2 character 5
if (!phantom.casperLoaded) )

Can you please guide me as to how to use the Closure Compiler, to optimize all of the JS files in the project with their dependencies, thus avoiding these errors and proceed further.

I went through the documentation for the Closure, but I wasn't able to figure out the approach needed in this case.

FYI: I was using the Closure compiler.jar

Comment: Why do you want to minify the casper scripts, which are intended to be run server-side only?

Comment: Hi, I wasn't trying to minify the core Casper Scripts. I was trying to minify the test scripts, after which verifying that they are able to run fine with the Casper invocation. Reason why I'm trying to do this is, my test scripts repository is another machine, and the Test Execution machine is different one (on which CasperJs & PhantomJs reside). When executing the tests, these test scripts would be pulled from the repository and I'm trying to get minified scripts so that some time can be saved. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Support has been added to Closure Compiler to make it is easier to work with [Common JS](http://www.commonjs.org/specs/) and [AMD/require.js](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html) modules using the following compiler flags:

- `--transform_amd_modules`
- `--process_common_js_modules`
- `--common_js_entry_module`
- `--common_js_module_path_prefix`

See [Experimental support for Common JS and AMD/require.js modules in Closure Compiler](http://www.nonblocking.io/2011/12/experimental-support-for-common-js-and.html)